# How to group and pick only certain values based on a field using select query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as follow

| ID | ORDERNO |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 456 |
| 2 | 456 |

During every select query done via application using JDBC, only the grouped records based on ORDERNO should be picked.

That means, for example, during first select query only details related to ID = 1, but we cannot specify the ID number in where clause because we do not know how many number of IDs will be there in future. So the query should yield only one set of records; application will delete those records after picking, hence next select query will result in picking other set of records. How to achieve it?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (oracle, mysql, postgres, microsoft sql server, etc)?

Comment: microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one option you could select on the MIN(ID) like:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM yourtable);
```

You could also use window functions to do this:

```
SELECT ID, ORDERNO
FROM 
    (
        SELECT ID, ORDERNO
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS dr
        FROM yourtable
    )dt
WHERE dr = 1;
```

Comment: I tried accepting the answer, but it is not showing up here

Comment: Second one looks inefficient, it will require scanning the whole table. The first version requires hitting the table twice.

Comment: @Charlieface I prefer your `WITH TIES` answer over both of these. I'm guessing that is the best performance.

Comment: Your second query is actually special-cased to compile down to a `TOP WITH TIES` in certain situations. See https://dbfiddle.uk/xOtC7-mB and https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/07/the-segment-top-query-optimisation.html One thing is for certain: none of these options will be performant without a covering index on `ID`

Comment: That's very interesting. I LOVE interesting optimization steps like that. I agree an index on ID is going to be pretty critical if this table is of any size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TOP WITH TIES` for this

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  t.ID,
  t.ORDERNO
FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY
  t.ID;
```

If you want to select and delete at the same time you could delete using an `OUTPUT` clause

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
      t.ID,
      t.ORDERNO
    FROM YourTable t
    ORDER BY
      t.ID
)
DELETE cte
OUTPUT deleted.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

order your rows and select top n number of rows that you want :

```
select top (1) with ties ID, ORDERNO
from tablename
order by ID asc
```

Comment: It only select the 1st row, but in my case, first 2 rows must be selected as both contains ID as 1

Comment: @christy1999 oh I see your point now , you can use to with ties